# Graphics glitches when I open web pages

Tags: video, intel

Whenever I'm browsing some websites, some graphics glitches appear, like in this screenshot:

[image]

This happens with any Linux distribution that I use. Sometimes, the windows of these programs themselves have these errors (only happened once in this case, however). What can be wrong here?

`lshw -C display`:

```
WARNING: You should run this program the super-user.
*-display
description: VGA compatible controller
Product: 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller
Manufacturer: Intel Corporation
physical id: 2
Bus information: pci @ 0000:00:02.0
Version: 10
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: driver = i915 latency = 0
resources: irq: 43 memory: fea80000-feafffff ioport: DC00 (size = 8)
memory:     e0000000-efffffff memory: fe900000-fe9fffff
```

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express DRAM Controller (rev 10)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 10)
00:1B.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1C.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01)
00:1C.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 01)
00:1D.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation USB UHCI N10/ICH 7 Family Controller # 1 (rev 01)
00:1D.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation USB UHCI N10/ICH 7 Family Controller # 2 (rev 01)
00:1D.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation USB UHCI N10/ICH 7 Family Controller # 3 (rev 01)
00:1D.3 USB Controller: Intel Corporation USB UHCI N10/ICH 7 Family Controller # 4 (rev 01)
00:1D.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation USB2 EHCI N10/ICH 7 Family Controller (rev 01)
00:1E.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1)
00:1F.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
00:1F.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 01)
00:1F.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation N10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 01)
00:1F.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation SMBus Controller N10/ICH 7 Family (rev 01)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
```